# Flight changing

Tags: airport-transfer

I booked ticket on jet airways from Rajkot to Nagpur ( One stop is in Mumbai),I have to change the plane to another both are jet airways only.
Ticket booked direct from Rajkot to Nagpur
The changing time is only 30 min. As per procedure check-in time closing before 45 min.
Then how can I change the flight

Comment: "[H]ow can I change the flight[?]" Do you mean how can you get tickets for a different flight instead, or how can you make your connection at Mumbai?

Answer (score 1):

The typical arrangement these days is that you check in for both legs of your journey either online or at your first departure airport, where you'll be given boarding cards for both flights.

So it should not be relevant for you when check-in closes in Mumbai; only travelers who *start out* there will need to worry about that time.